# Ошибка java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: java, android

Есть три страницы наследованные от Fragment

И в одном из них создаются еще 2 фрагмента.

```
public class Info extends TabFragment {

private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private ExpandableListView expListView;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private List<CityInfo> cityinfo;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private FragmentActivity mycontext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mycontext = (FragmentActivity) context;
    super.onAttach(context);
}

  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     try{
        FragmentManager fm =  ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, new ListCity(cityinfo));
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   cityinfo = InternetConnect.getCityInfo();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps_city, container, false);

    FrameLayout _simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_element_layout);
    ((TextView) tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.TabMenu)).setText("СПИСОК");


    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(R.layout.tab_element_layout);
    TextView tv = ((TextView) tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.TabMenu));
    tv.setText("КАРТА");
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mycontext.getAssets(), getString(R.string.digit_keyboard_font));


    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 1:
                    fragment = new MapsActivity(cityinfo);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    fragment = new ListCity(cityinfo);
                    break;

            }
            FragmentManager fm = mycontext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });




    return view;
}
```

}

При перемещении по фрагментам быстро вылетает ошибка

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28641
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f100110 (com.example.myapplication:id/simpleFrameLayout) for fragment ListCity{294f7a4f #2 id=0x7f100110}
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
```

Если убрать эти строки , то ошибка пропадает но при переходе на нужный фрагмент он пустой.

```
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     try{
        FragmentManager fm =  ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, new ListCity(cityinfo));
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/simpleTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/white"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/TabItem"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="СПИСОК"

        style="@style/TabItem"
        android:layout_margin="50dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="КАРТА"
        android:padding="50dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/simpleFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку фрагмента с табами

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил, тут все стандартно

Comment: Попробуйте анимацию убрать, т.е. `ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нечего не изменилось. Такое ощущение что onViewCreated запускается когда еще не подгружена разметка или уже выгружена из памяти. Как сделать так чтобы при открытии Таба загружался первый фрагмент так сказать, другим способом?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по тому, что Вы пытаетесь разместить фрагмент в `onViewCreated`, Вы это делаете не внутри активити, а внутри другого фрагмента. В таких случаях стоит использовать [`Fragment.getChildFragmentManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) фрагмента, а не `FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager` активити. Правда вложенные фрагменты поддерживаются только начиная с Android 4.2 (API 17), подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672066/fragment-inside-fragment).

Практика показывает, что на самом деле можно разместить фрагмент внутри `View` другого фрагмент, вероятно, это получится и у вас, если сделать это с некоторой задержкой после `onViewCreated` (например, с помощью `Handler.postDelayed`). Однако, не рекомендую так делать, поскольку в дальнейшем у Вас начнутся проблемы, если Вы попытаетесь убрать/заменить фрагмент-контейнер. С использованием `getChildFragmentManager()` таких проблем не будет.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно исправил изменил  `((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();`
на `getChildFragmentManager` и добавил пустой конструктор в ListCity и вроде пока не выкидывает